# Some static files in django serve 404 when other dont- any ideas why?

Tags: django, static-files, django-1.5

Using django 1.5

I got static files configured like this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/<user>/Projects/<name>/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

i just run manage.py collectstatic

directory listing:

```
static/css
static/css/bootstrap.css
static/css/addressbook.css
static/css/bootstrap-responsive.css
static/css/rewrite.css
static/css/login.css
```

when I type
 localhost:8000/static/css/addressbook.css i got 404

but:

localhost:8000/static/css/bootstrap.css

gives me a proper css content

WTF? they are in the same folder and have same user/rights/groups

part from menage.py runserver output:

```
[24/Jul/2013 12:18:19] "GET /static/css/addressbook.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1663
[24/Jul/2013 12:19:16] "GET /static/css/login.css HTTP/1.1" 200 533
[24/Jul/2013 12:20:12] "GET /static/css/addressbook.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1663
[24/Jul/2013 12:32:51] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

**UPDATE:**

It's serving files not from "project/static" but from static folder under application folder
I figure that out by deleting static forder under one app - files start to give 404. Same if I disable AppDirectoriesFinder.
But it still not consistent some applications don't serve files even from "static" under application folder.

My ideal situation will be: AppDirectoriesFinder commented out and all files served from `myProject/static/`

Comment: Did you check .css file permissions?

Comment: What's the value of the `DEBUG` setting?

Comment: i checked permissions, DEBUG is True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Here's my solution:

Add this to your settings.py

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    #"django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder"
)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Comment: can I ask what causes the problem? could you please describe it a little bit? (helped me as well)

Answer (score 3):

You can't just drop files into the /static folder of your **project**. Django doesn't "see" files in that directory unless they were collected from the apps via collectstatic. You will get a 404 trying to access files that you drop in there manually.

You need to put static files into the /static directory of an **app** (if it doesn't belong in a specific app, just create a new one, for example "main" or "website").

Alternatively you can set the STATICFILES_DIRS for Django to search additional directories when you call collectstatic.